# Making asp.net login faster

Tags: performance, asp.net-membership

I am using ASP.NET membership roles. The login is painfully slow (30-40 sec). Every time you login. After researching, I came to conclusion that I need to adjust the connection setting. I found one useful post [Asp.Net Login Control very slow initial connection to Non-Trusted AD Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/946550/777982) which address the probelem from Active Directory (AD) point of view. I am not using AD though. If I apply the setting mentioned in the above post

```
connectionProtection="None"
```

I get this error

**Attribute not recognized 'connectionProtection'**

My connection string in web.config looks like this

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="115">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
connectionStringName="MyConn" 
applicationName="/MyApplication" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
enablePasswordReset="true" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
passwordFormat="Hashed" 
/>
```

What change do I need to make and where to make the login faster? Everything is on the same PC. We are not using SSL.

My Connections string to SQL are:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="MyConn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

SQL Profiler (AnjProfiler) gives me this result when connecting to the database. Query No. 1 is probably generated by ASP.NET membership itself.

[image]

Comment: Can you post you connectionstring? Are you using an attached database or a local SQL instance (Express or Full)?

Comment: a local sql instance, sorry am not at my desk now.

Comment: Pretty sure query number 1 is a side effect of using SQL profiler. Have you run a .Net profiler to see what's going on?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It is produced by AnjProfiler itself.