# ASP .net forms authentication very slow on first login

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

I have a web application (.net 4.0) with forms authentication (username and password).  I have been trying to track down an issue with a slow login, and have come to the conclusion that on the initial login the page takes anywhere from 20-50seconds to login, and each subsequent logins (logoff and log back in) take an average of 3 seconds.  What is causing this to take so long on an initial login?  Most users will only log into the site once a day, so this seems like the site is slow, when in actuality it appears to be just the initial login.

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1"
   CssClass="login"
   runat="server"
   InstructionText="Please enter your information."
   CheckBoxStyle - CssClass="loginRememberMe"
   RememberMeText="Remember Me"
   width="300px"
   Height="150px"
   onloggingin="Login1_LoggingIn"
   onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">

   <TitleTextStyle CssClass="loginHeader" /> 
   <TextBoxStyle CssClass="loginInput" />
   <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="loginButton" />
   <InstructionTextStyle Font - Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" / >

 </asp:Login>


protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    Login login = (Login)loginview1.FindControl("Login1");
    MembershipProvider prov = Membership.Providers["AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"];
    if (prov.ValidateUser(login.UserName, login.Password))
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;

        AuthenticatedUser.ConnectionString = "PortalConnectionString";
        AuditUserLogin(login.UserName, true);

    }
    else
    {
        AuditUserLogin(login.UserName, false);
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}

private void AuditUserLogin(string Username, bool Authenticated)
{
    AuditLog.LogUserLoginAttempt(Username, Authenticated, getIP());
}

protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
  //todo
}
```

Comment: Is this the INITIAL login (after an iisreset), or is this the initial login for a specific user?

Comment: @JTorres I am not sure, to test this we logged in with multiple credentials in increments of a few minutes, and I am not sure if IIS was doing a reset each time or what, how do I check that?  IIS 7.0

Comment: Unless you were manually resetting it, chances are the ApplicationPool /IIS was not being reset during that time frame.  When you testing it "every few minutes," when was it slow?  When each user hitting the same webpage logged in, or only the first person to hit it?

Comment: @JTorres it was only for the first user logging in, after that they were fine.

Comment: Chances are it was just the delay in the spin-up of your Membership provider.  If that is the case, only the first user of the day will receive that hit.  Assuming your production site will have a warmup script after maintenance/reboot/etc, most people would consider this a "non-issue."

Comment: Something like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946550/asp-net-login-control-very-slow-initial-connection-to-non-trusted-ad-domain) may be helpful.

Comment: @JTorres Great, I will continue my testing to see if there are any other instances of the slowness. Is there anyway to speed it up if I had to?

Comment: What are you using as a backend store for your Forms Authentication?  If you're using Active Directory, you could look at the SO post I linked to above or even here if the issue is secure/unsecured ports: https://elgg.leeds.ac.uk/webteam/weblog/15385.html

Comment: @JTorres we are using SQL server with the asp membership tables

Comment: Are you using an form of STS? I've experienced greater than 60-second response times during an initial login requests, with subsequent requests being near instantaneous.  A solution has not yet been found, (my example is a SP 2010/ASP.NET 3.5 solution), but it has been traced to the STS service.