# Slow ASP.NET response. VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED in IIS Failed Request Log

Tags: asp.net, api, iis, asp.net-web-api

A new service on our website makes a request to our API which is running on .NET Framework 4.7.2 in IIS 10.

The main request takes over 8 seconds to respond.

After enabling Failed Request Tracing to try and track down the issue, I have found a single module causing the issue.

[image: Slow ASP.Net service. Problem module identified]

I am really struggling to find the solution to this. The service is a Web API and doesn't use forms authentication. It uses custom authentication with a signed JWT that is passed in a bearer header.

What is causing me to have 4 unresolved virtual modules?
And is this lack of resolution causing the 7.1 second delay?

Thanks

Comment: The actual delay was probably caused by ASP.NET in place compilation of your web app (which happened when `ManagedPipelineHandler` was chosen in step 21. So you should follow the tips in https://csharp.wekeepcoding.com/article/20133481/IIS+7.5+web+application+first+request+after+app-pool+recycle+very+slow to optimize the site.

Comment: First of all, it is recommended that you check the source code to see if there is a loop or it takes a long time. You can debug the application step by step. If the page is large, rendering will also take a long time. I think it is more likely to be caused by the source code. You can also try to configure ASP.NET Impersonation in web.config: <identity impersonate="true" />.

Comment: This has a similar question, you can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286111/asp-net-forms-authentication-very-slow-on-first-login